# associated Angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to make grouped ui-select, in fact each ui-select option depends on the previous one.
for example I have a list of levels in the first UI-select, and then depending on the first ui-select selected Item a list of place number will be displayed on the second ui-select.
is that possible?
here is my code, but I wasn't yet able to implemnt it :(

```
<div class="SumoSelect sumo_somename" tabindex="0" style="width:80%">
        <ui-select search-enabled=false ng-model="levelNumber.selected"
                        theme="bootstrap" append-to-body="true" on-select="getListPlacePerLevel(levelNumber.selected)">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected.levelNumber}}</ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in levels">
                    <span ng-bind="item.levelNumber"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
    </div>
    <div class="SumoSelect sumo_somename" tabindex="0" style="width:80%; margin-top:20px;">
        <ui-select search-enabled=false ng-model="item.selected"
                        theme="bootstrap" append-to-body="true">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected.item}}</ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in levelNumber.selected.listPlaceNumber">
                    <span ng-bind="item"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
    </div>
```

and my Json data is as below

```
[{"levelNumber":1,"listPlaceNumber":[1,2,3,4,6]},{"levelNumber":2,"listPlaceNumber":[2,4,6,7]},{"levelNumber":3,"listPlaceNumber":[11,12,13,14,16]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this plunk works for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2kiQ7W?p=preview

Relevant Code:

```
<div tabindex="0" style="width:80%">
    <ui-select search-enabled="false" ng-model="levelNumber.selected" theme="bootstrap" append-to-body="true" on-select="getListPlacePerLevel(levelNumber.selected)">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected.levelNumber}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in levels">
            <span ng-bind="item.levelNumber"></span>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
<div tabindex="0" style="width:80%; margin-top:20px;">
    <ui-select search-enabled="false" ng-model="item.selected" theme="bootstrap" append-to-body="true" on-select="getListPlacePerLevel($select.selected)">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in levelNumber.selected.listPlaceNumber">
            <span ng-bind="item"></span>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```